# Column value display wrong when export CSV in magento 2 admin UI component grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, uicomponent

In my custom module admin **UI component** data grid there is a one column is named **"Status"** all data display perfectly.

But my problem is when i export data then **"Status"** column value display **0** OR **1** because in DATABASE value is stored as 0 and 1

And what i want is 
When i export - then in csv file that status values should be **0** => **Pending** 
and for **1** => **Active** how can i achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override **getRowData()** function of `vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php`

This function print row data to csv or xml file at the time of export

So you final code will look like:

```
public function getRowData(DocumentInterface $document, $fields, $options)
{
    $row = [];
    $key = array_search ('status', $fields);
    foreach ($fields as $column) {
        if (isset($options[$column])) {
            $key = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
            if (isset($options[$column][$key])) {
                $row[] = $options[$column][$key];
            } else {
                $row[] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $row[] = $document->getCustomAttribute($column)->getValue();
            if($column == 'status'){
                switch ($row[$key]){
                case 0:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_PENDING;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_INACTIVE;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_DISAPPROVED;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_VACATION_MODE;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $row[$key] = self::STATUS_CLOSED;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```